# Use Path variable with an object created by CreateTextFile (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, text-files

I'm trying to use the path variable with an object created via but I'm getting an error `438: Object Doesn’t Support this Property or Method`:

```
Dim FSO As Object
Dim Text FileAs Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set TextFile= FSO.CreateTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FSO.GetBaseName(ThisWorkbook.FullName) & "_TextFile" & ".txt")
Debug.Print TextFile.Path
```

What's the problem here? Is there any way to get the path from the created object directly? I'm trying to avoid creating an additional variable for the path.

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ missed those two, thanks, it's corrected now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FSO.CreateTextFile "Creates a specified file name and returns a TextStream object that can be used to read from or write to the file." There isn't a Path property in TextStream so the Debug.Print TextFile.Path return error, after of course correcting the two mistakes I pointed out in the comment

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createtextfile-method

Answer (score 3):

### TextStream Object vs File Object (FileSystemObject)

- [CreateTextFile Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createtextfile-method)
- [TextStream Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/textstream-object)
- [File Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/file-object)

**Wrong**

```
'Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    
    Dim fso As Object
    ' Compile Error: Syntax error
    Dim TextFileAs Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    ' With 'Option Explicit':
    ' Compile error: Variable not defined
    ' The procedure's signature ('Sub Test()') is highlighted in yellow.
    ' 'objFSO' is highlighted in blue. It is fairly obvious what's wrong.
    ' Without 'Option Explicit:
    ' Run-time error '424': Object required
    ' The whole 'Set TextFile...' line is highlighted in yellow.
    ' Hard to figure out what's wrong.
    Set TextFile = fso.CreateTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" _
        & objFSO.GetBaseName(ThisWorkbook.FullName) & "_TextFile" & ".txt")
    ' Run-time error '438': Object doesn’t support this property or method
    Debug.Print TextFile.Path

End Sub
```

**Correct**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' To get the base name, you could just use the workbook name
    ' instead of the full name.
    Dim TextFilePath As String: TextFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path _
        & "\" & fso.GetBaseName(ThisWorkbook.Name) & "_TextFile" & ".txt"
    
    ' TextStream object: has no path or name
    Dim TextFile As Object: Set TextFile = fso.CreateTextFile(TextFilePath, True)
    ' e.g.
    'TextFile.WriteLine "This is a test."
    ' Close it when done modifying:
    TextFile.Close
        
    ' File object: has a path and a name
    Dim tFile As Object: Set tFile = fso.GetFile(TextFilePath)
    Debug.Print tFile.Name, tFile.Path

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll find ΑΓΡΙΑ ΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ a little bit more compact, so I set the check mark there, although you were first, if that's ok. But a +1 anyway.